# Validate if RSA key matches X.509 certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, rsa, x509, pem

I have a RSA Key and a X.509 Certificate which I use for SSL connections.

The key and certificate are stored in files in PEM format (generated by OpenSSL) and used in an Apache HTTP server environment.

Is there an easy way to validate if the key matches the certificate using only Java code (without executing the openssl binary and parsing the output), for example by using Java security and/or Bouncycastle library methods?

Comment: In addition to owlstead's answer, OWASP offers a Android Java example on Public Key Pinning at [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). It uses a custom `TrustManager` since that's the Java way. I don't believe there's any difference between Sun Java and Android Java for the code in question.

Answer (score 4):

The following code compares the SHA-1 over the modulus within the public and private key. The modulus should be unique for each pair (unless you key pair generation mechanism or random generator is broken of course).

Note that the following code requires the key to be in unencrypted PKCS#8 format. It may be better to use PKCS#12 instead and load the binary PKCS#12 file in a KeyStore (providing the password).

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in key.pem -out keypk8.pem -nocrypt
```

And finally the Java code:

```
import static org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;

public class CompareCertAndKey {

    /**
     * Checks if the certificate and RSA private key match.
     * 
     * @param args the path to the certificate file in args[0] and that of the private key in args[1]
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final PemReader certReader = new PemReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            final PemObject certAsPemObject = certReader.readPemObject();
            if (!certAsPemObject.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CERTIFICATE")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Certificate file does not contain a certificate but a " + certAsPemObject.getType());
            }
            final byte[] x509Data = certAsPemObject.getContent();
            final CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
            final Certificate cert = fact.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(x509Data));
            if (!(cert instanceof X509Certificate)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Certificate file does not contain an X509 certificate");
            }

            final PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
            if (!(publicKey instanceof RSAPublicKey)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Certificate file does not contain an RSA public key but a " + publicKey.getClass().getName());
            }

            final RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
            final byte[] certModulusData = rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray();

            final MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            final byte[] certID = sha1.digest(certModulusData);
            final String certIDinHex = toHexString(certID);


            final PemReader keyReader = new PemReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
            final PemObject keyAsPemObject = keyReader.readPemObject();
            if (!keyAsPemObject.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("PRIVATE KEY")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key file does not contain a private key but a " + keyAsPemObject.getType());
            }

            final byte[] privateKeyData = keyAsPemObject.getContent();
            final KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            final KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyData);
            final PrivateKey privateKey = keyFact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
            if (!(privateKey instanceof RSAPrivateKey)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key file does not contain an X509 encoded private key");
            }
            final RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey;
            final byte[] keyModulusData = rsaPrivateKey.getModulus().toByteArray();
            final byte[] keyID = sha1.digest(keyModulusData);
            final String keyIDinHex = toHexString(keyID);

            System.out.println(args[0] + " : " + certIDinHex);
            System.out.println(args[1] + " : " + keyIDinHex);
            if (certIDinHex.equalsIgnoreCase(keyIDinHex)) {
                System.out.println("Match");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No match");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 As usual, a very detailed answer. However, it saddens me if this is the most concise way of achieving this goal. I'd have hoped Java standard libs (or a third-party library) would make this a one-liner (ignoring, of course, the reading of the data from files).

Comment: @Duncan there are a lot of choices to be made along the way. The easiest way of making this simpler is to create an OpenSSL compatability layer. But OpenSSL is huge and not documented all that well.

Comment: How can I convert the PEM Certificate to pkcs8 in Java (without invoking OpenSSL)?

Comment: OpenSSL has its own file formats, I'm not sure that is possible without programming.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the above code snippet. Its working for me with bouncycastle version 1.51

```
<bcprov-jdk15on-version>1.51</bcprov-jdk15on-version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>${bcprov-jdk15on-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Many Thanks for your code snippet.